# How do I add texture to new faces on an already-textured mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry

I finished modeling and making a texture for a coyote, but then decided I'd like to add some planes behind the legs and around the ruff so that I can add a texture that will make the coyote look more bushy. Below is a picture of my coyote with some rudimentary MS paint lines where I'd like to add planes that will simulate spiky fur when viewed from the side.

[image]

I can easily add more planes for the fringe, but in order to apply texture to them, I'd have to create a new UV wrap, which will make the UV map around which I based my existing texture useless. Is there an easy way to add faces and textures to an already-textured object without ending up with an entirely new UV map?

Thanks!

Comment: You can add a second separate map for the new faces, but I'm not sure if this is what you want..

Comment: I think you could just select the new vertices, and press U and the unwrapping method you want, this should only add new UV vertices, not remove the old ones.

Comment: @gandalf3: Personally, this is exactly what I DON'T want. A new face 'spawned' in my edited (already textured) geometry. I selected it, pressed 'U', 'Unwrap', and it appeared on an entirely blank, new UV map instead of getting added to the existing one... what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Like someonewithpc said, you can simply create the new geometry for the fringe and add it to the existing UV map:

1. Create the new geometry
2. In Edit mode, deselect everything then select only the new geometry
3. With your cursor in the 3D view, type 'U' and select your preferred method of UV unrwapping
4. In the UV/Image Editor, select the new geometry and place it in an unused portion of the texture. (Hopefully you have some blank spots in the image. If not, you're out of luck)

The new geometry should be part of the UV map, and the existing UV map will remain unchanged.